# How to fix the jQuery so the bubbles in my code get disappear when user click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think my jQuery code is not working. When I click on the bubbles it should disappear but nothing is happening. I tried pasting this one codepen and it works over there but it does not work when I do it on sublime text or any other editor. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ffccff;
    }
    
    .circle {
      width: 30%;
      background: #e6ffff;
      padding-bottom: 30%;
      float: left;
      margin: 1.66%;
      border-radius: 90px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
    }
    
    #container {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .visible {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(".circle").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".restart").click(function() {
      $(".circle").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button class="restart">Restart</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy your code to jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r9zda0cv/
Everything works.

Try to wrap up your javascript in ready

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ffccff;
    }

    .circle {
      width: 30%;
      background: #e6ffff;
      padding-bottom: 30%;
      float: left;
      margin: 1.66%;
      border-radius: 90px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
    }

    #container {
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .visible {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).on("ready", function(){
    $(".circle").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".restart").click(function() {
      $(".circle").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    });

  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button class="restart">Restart</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Even after wrapping the javascript function in "ready", it still does not work on Sublime text. But it seems to work on every online text editor.

Comment: Hmm. Try to move your script to the end of body or put it to seperate file. Check if jquery really gets is loaded. Is there any errors in console? Why dont you use the newest jquery?

Comment: Nah moving script to other place wont change anything. I Will check your code locally, tommorow